# Is it better practice to have one URL for each bulk update or many URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have a user maintenance page.  This page has a list of users where the admin can do bulk updates on the users he selects.  Bulk updates include:  activate, deactivate, and update roles to.

Should there be one URL I POST to, such as `/users/bulk_update.json`, where I then pass in the list of IDs and the method type.  And in my bulk_update action, I update the IDs according to the method.

Or should there be a URL for each method, such `/users/bulk_update_activate`, `/users/bulk_update_deactivate`, and `/users/bulk_update_roles`?

Comment: URLs like this are much more procedural that RESTful... the URL itself speaks to the **action** being taken rather than focusing on the **representation**.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answers is: it depends! :)

If your updates type share many of the code logic.

1) Use filter:

```
class FirstController < ApplicationController
  # Other controller code

  before_filter :prepare_update
  after_filter :finalize_update

  def bulk_update_activate
    # Do something here
  end

  def bulk_update_deactivate
    # Do something here
  end
end
```

2) Use a single action:

```
class SecondController < ApplicationController
  # Other controller code

  def bulk_update
    case params[:operation]
      when :activate then
        # Do something here
      when :deactivate then
        # Do something here
    end
  end
end
```

If your updates are completely indipendent, then you should write different actions.

In my projects I usually find myself in using the first approach.

Hope it will be useful.